# Reimplimenting QSqlRelationalTableModel - data Function Returning String Not Code

Tags: python, mysql, qt, pyqt, qsqltablemodel

Am subclassing QSqlRelationalTableModel.

```
class Titles(QSqlRelationalTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QSqlRelationalTableModel.__init__(self)

        self.setTable("titles")
        self.setRelation(self.fieldIndex("type"), QSqlRelation("title_type", "id", "type"))         
        self.select()

        print self.record(0).value("title").toString() # 1

    def data(self, i, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            print  self.record(0).value("title").toString() # 2 
            return self.record(0).value("title").toString() # 3

titles = Titles() 

print iswcTitlesModel.record(0).value("title").toString() # 4
```

All the above prints space (it returns the correct amount of rows, but only as blank space).
If the data function is removed, #1 & #4 print.
If doing return "string", all items are populated.  The model is instantiated, and the intended return code works outside the model's definition.  Tried multiple other SQL tables, all with a Relation, but even without a relation it doesn't work.  Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
def data(self, i, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if i.column() == 1:
                return QVariant("col 1 custom data")
            else:
                return super(QSqlTableModel, self).data(i, role)
```

So if i.column() == the desired column, display whatever you want.  Otherwise, return data that the super class (QSqlTableModel) had already mapped into the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the domain within the relation

```
    self.setRelation(self.fieldIndex("type"), QSqlRelation("title_type", "title_type"."id", "title_type"."type"))
```

Had similar problems, as `"id"` was in both tables

Comment: Hi ngulam, thanks for the reply.  The solution didn't make any difference, but am in Python 2.7.  Even without a relation, the data still doesn't return, so it seems more why self.record(0).value("title").toString() isn't working (it does return, but only blank space), but return "string" does work.  Regards